# Filtering Log Output on Separate Lines

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, grep, regular-expression

I did a recursive grep in a directory to find all files that would match as follows

```
grep -ER "match_string1|match_string2" /path/to/dir/
```

What I get as output is:

```
/path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string1
/path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string2
/path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string2
```

Where match_string1 represents a model#
Where match_string2 represents a test result

I would like to merge the lines so that I can say when model# and test result match specific criteria then count

Note: It is fine to have double match_string2 on the same line as match_string1

Example output I would expect:

```
/path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string1; /path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string2; /path/to/dir/timestamp.log:match_string2
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: In above example you want to double `match_string2` in one line with `match_string1` or not? Or may be better to show the finish purpose what you'd like to calculate?

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you say "match_string1 is x", what do you mean by "is x"? And what do you want on the same line? Note that grep outputs the entire line that matches, not just the pattern.

Comment: Bjorn I updated the question to be a little more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/match_string1/{
     :1
     N
     /\n.*match_string2/s/\n/; /
     t1
     P
     D
                     }'
```

When script met line with `match_string1` it add next line to pattern and check if in that added line there is `match_string2` if so they substitute `n`ewline sign by `;` and add next line to check. If there is not `match_string2` (so substitution haven't made) the script prints first line and start process from beginning with second line.

Comment: Which part of the sed script is the part that defines whether or not to check the next line? Where is it making the decision whether or not to keep looking for the match in the next line?

Comment: @rainereality If in line meet `match_string1` script adds next line and check it for `match_string2` presence

Comment: What arguments are doing that is that the :1 or the N? I don't understand the purpose of the t1, the P and the D either.

Comment: This is `/match_string1/`. `N` add next line, `t1` return script to `:1` position **only if** previous substitution by `s` is succeed. `P` prints first line (may be long with all added `match_string2`), `D` delete ones and return to the begin and process the second line which remains in memory (pattern space)

Comment: you're awesome! know anywhere that has some good example usage of sed functions so I can familiarize myself more with sed conditions and functions?

Comment: @rainereality There are many sed-maniacs on the SE